# Merging tables based on an identical column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

I have two tables that have an identical `link` column, one containing the rest of my data and one containing some date fields (hereby `col1`, `col2`, `col3`) that I need to import into the existing table. I tried the following query without success:

```
alter table (existing_table)
```

`add column (col1)`
`add column (col2)`
`add column (col3)`

```
insert into [existing_table].[col1]
select (col1)
from [import_table]
where [import_table].[LINK] = [existing_table].[LINK]

insert into [existing_table].[col2]
select (col2)
from [import_table]
where [import_table].[LINK] = [existing_table].[LINK]

insert into [existing_table].[col3]
select (col3)
from [import_table]
where [import_table].[LINK] = [existing_table].[LINK]
```

This resulted in a number of errors, and I then attempted the above in separate chunks. Whenever I tried to run it, Access requested a value for `[existing_table].[LINK]`. As this is an identical column to `[import_table].[LINK]`, and therefore is an ambiguous value, I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be performing an UPDATE and not an INSERT.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE [existing_table]
SET [existing_table].[col1] = [import_table].[col1], [existing_table].[col2] = [import_table].[col2], [existing_table].[col3] = [import_table].[col3]
FROM [existing_table] INNER JOIN
    [import_table] ON [existing_table].[LINK] = [import_table].[LINK]
```